# How to update part of a json, using JSON_MODIFY

Tags: sql-server, spring-data-jpa

I am using mssql as DB and storing all details as a json String.

Now i want to update part of a json object.

How to do that?

Below is the json Object.

```
{"customerName":"mohan","salesForceUrl":"erferf","notes":"ferfer","custId":"3bc5a660-c001-11e9-84a1-11b306ffa283","deleteInd":"N","createdDate":1565944718619,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"deletedDate":null,"feeds":[]}
```

when i want to update everything except feeds which is an array, how to do that, i am using JPA @Query for this.

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value="update Customers set configJSON = JSON_MODIFY(configJSON, '$.customerName', 'mohan') where CustomerId = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
    @Transactional
    public void updateCutomer(String custId);
```

Customers is the table name
configJSON is the column name.

Comment: Using `JSON_MODIFY(configJSON, '$.customerName', 'mohan')` is one possible approach. What's wrong with this statement?

Comment: i want to update everything except feeds

Comment: as i am getting details from the UI as part of customer update info.

Comment: If I understand, you need a T-SQL statement to update the row in a table with the content of the input JSON text, based on `"custId"` value in this JSON? And, what is your SQL Server version? Thanks.

Comment: yes,sql server 2016. In the same JSON i am keeping all data, but as i have an UI.

the below are part of customer module, so when i want to update the customer module, i need to update all except the feeds[].

Hope you understand the problem.
"customerName":"mohan","salesForceUrl":"erferf","notes":"ferfer","custId":"3bc5a660-c001-11e9-84a1-11b306ffa283","deleteInd":"N","createdDate":1565944718619,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"deletedDate":null

Comment: @Zhorov, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to extract the `$.feeds` part from the current `JSON`, update the input `JSON` with this `$.feeds` part and finally update the table with the modified input `JSON`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
   customerId int,
   configJSON nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO Customers
   (customerId, configJSON)
VALUES
   (1, N'{"customerName":"xxx", "custId":"3bc5a660-c001-11e9-84a1-11b306ffa283", "feeds":[{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}]}')
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"customerName":"mohan","salesForceUrl":"erferf","notes":"ferfer","custId":"3bc5a660-c001-11e9-84a1-11b306ffa283","deleteInd":"N","createdDate":1565944718619,"lastUpdatedDate":null,"deletedDate":null,"feeds":[]}'
UPDATE Customers
SET configJSON = JSON_MODIFY(
   @json,
   '$.feeds',
   JSON_QUERY(configJSON, '$.feeds')
)
WHERE customerId = 1
```

Comment: i didnt understand this, can you please explain this?

i want something like this...

Modifying
 Query(value="update Customers set configJSON = JSON_MODIFY(configJSON, configJSON, ?1) where CustomerId = ?2", nativeQuery=true)
 @Transactional
 public void updateCutomer(String custJson, String custId);

where i will get the new Json as well as the custId for which i need to do that ipdate

Comment: @mohan I'm not familiar with JPA, but probably the statement should look like this: `UPDATE Customers SET configJSON = JSON_MODIFY(?1, '$.feeds', JSON_QUERY(configJSON, '$.feeds')) WHERE CustomerId = ?2`.

Comment: @Zhorov...i do have an issue...can you help me?

Comment: @mohan What's the issue? Thanks.

Comment: if i have below json,

{"customerName":"mohan","custId":"e35273d0-c002-11e9-8188-a1525f580dfd","feeds":[{"feedId":"57f221d0-c310-11e9-8af7-cf1cf42fc72e","feedName":"ccsdcdscsdc","format":"MS Excel","sources":[{"sourceId":69042417,"name":"TV 2 Livsstil"},{"sourceId":69042419,"name":"Turk Max"}]},{"feedId":"59bbd360-c312-11e9-8af7-cf1cf42fc72e","feedName":"dfgdfgdfgdfgsdfg","format":"XmlTV","sources":[{"sourceId":69042417,"name":"TV 2 Livsstil"},{"sourceId":69042419,"name":"Turk Max"}]}]}

if i am passing custId and feedID how to update specific feed with the new feed that in tsql?

Comment: i found this query, which will bring the feed...but after getting this how to replace this with the new feed.

SELECT * FROM ExtractsConfiguration.dbo.Customers AS Customer
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( configJSON, '$.feeds' ) AS Config
    WHERE
        Customer.CustomerId = 'custId'
        AND JSON_VALUE( Config.value, '$.feedId' ) = 'feedId'

Comment: @mohan Probably you should ask another question, with full example data. I think, that similar approach, using JSON_MODIFY should work in tnis new scenario. Thanks.

Comment: i have asked that question, can you please see the below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591635/how-to-update-a-nested-array-in-json-in-mssql/57597734?noredirect=1#comment101682822_57597734